# Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Tags: ios, swift

I have a lazy parameter that I'm attempting to call a helper function in:

```
class ColumnNode: SCNNode {

    lazy var upperColumnNode: SCNNode = {
        return buildColumPart()
    }()

    func buildColumPart() -> SCNNode {
        var node = SCNNode()
        ...
        return node
    }
}
```

Unfortunately on line `return buildColumPart()` I am getting:

```
Missing argument for parameter #1 in call
```

What exactly does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `self` to access instance methods in lazy properties:

```
class ColumnNode: SCNNode {

    lazy var upperColumnNode: SCNNode = {
        return self.buildColumPart()
    }()

    func buildColumPart() -> SCNNode {
        var node = SCNNode()
        ...
        return node
    }
}
```

Interestingly enough, the reason it's complaining about parameter #1 is that instance methods are *actually* class methods that take an instance as a parameter and return a closure with the instance captured - instead of `self.buildColumPart()`, you could instead call `buildColumPart(self)()`.

Comment: That is very interesting. Thanks for the in-depth explanation